# php foreach get all data from database table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I would like to get all the values of: `echo "<td class=\"points\">" . $row2['PIY'] . "/" . $row2['PIK'] .  "</td>";` Some how it only returns the first on. After that i would like to calculate the sum of them.

At the moment the code only gets the first.

```
echo "<table class=\"zebra\">";
$sum1=0;
$sum2=0;
$numbering =1;
$query2 = "SELECT pisteet_1 As PIY, pisteet_2 as PIK, nimi As NIM, opisto As OPI, pisteet.kaupunki_id As KA FROM
 pisteet INNER JOIN joukkueet ON joukkueet.id = pisteet.team_id INNER JOIN oppilaitokset ON oppilaitokset.opisto_id = joukkueet.opisto_id GROUP BY nimi, team_id ORDER BY team_id ASC";

foreach ($db->query($query2) as $row2) {
    echo "<tr class=\"all " . $row2['KA'] . "\">";
    echo "<td>" . $numbering . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row2['NIM'] ."<span>" . $row2['OPI'] ."</span></td>";

//--------should get all the points----------
    echo "<td class=\"points\">" . $row2['PIY'] . "/" . $row2['PIK'] .  "</td>";
    $sum1 +=$row2['PIY'];
    $sum2 +=$row2['PIK'];
    echo '<td class="Sum">'.$sum1.'/'.$sum2."</td>";
//-------------------------------------------

    echo "</tr>";
    $numbering ++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Which database interface are you using here?

Comment: @tadman i am using PDO.

Comment: I would suggest moving your query outside of your for loop so you can do some processing on it and turn it into a proper array before looping through it. It could be that the problem lies in the query and you wouldn't know if before you begin looping.

Comment: what happens if you run the query directly in your db, because your code seems to be correct

Comment: The same. i only get the first row of `$row2['PIY'] . "/" . $row2['PIK']` for every loop

Comment: @the_pete Do you mean using: `$query2->execute();
$result = $query2->fetchAll();`?

Comment: Yes, gather your results into an array and THEN loop through that array.